# Find embedded document by id in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

how can I find embedded document by _id in mongoid?
I have `Childrens` embedded `Parent` and I want to find one by its id:

`Parent.where('children._id' => BSON::ObjectId(children_id).first`

But this is returning a `Parent` containing the `Children` of given ID, not the `Children` itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the parent - just iterate through and search for the children in the children array

```
children = parent.children.select {|child| child._id == children_id }
```